# Inconsistent block signature checking on assignment

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a class with a block property which is used to configure table view cells:

```
    typedef void(^MyBlockDef)(UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath);

    @interface MyClass : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, copy) MyBlockDef foo;
    @end
```

And assigning to the property works as you would expect:

```
    obj.foo = ^(UITableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        MyTableViewCell *myCell = (MyTableViewCell *)cell;
        // configure myCell...
    };
```

However, in the block I always need to cast the cell parameter to my subclass when I want to configure it.  I would much prefer to specify my cell subclass in the block signature when I know it will be a particular type:

```
    obj.foo = ^(MyTableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        // configure cell...
    };
```

But when I do this, the compiler complains:

```
    error: incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'MyBlockDef' (aka 'void (^)(UITableViewCell *__strong, NSIndexPath *__strong)') from 'void (^)(MyTableViewCell *__strong, NSIndexPath *__strong)'
```

Is there a way around this, or some check I can turn off?  I totally understand why it thinks this is an error, but since the complier doesn't complain when the block parameter is specified as `id` it just seems a little inconsistent:

```
    obj.foo = ^(id cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
      MyTableViewCell *myCell = (MyTableViewCell *)cell;
      // configure myCell...
    };
```

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `typedef void(^MyBlockDef)(id cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath);` and then you can use either `UITableViewCell` or `MyTableViewCell` class without incident.

Comment: Yeah, but then you lose the understanding that it is supposed to be a UITableViewCell or subclass that you receive.

Comment: Yep. My only point is that if you use `id` in your typedef, you can use the more concise `obj.foo = ^(MyTableViewCell *cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath){ ... };` syntax. But if it bothers you that your interface no longer makes the class of the first parameter explicit, then go ahead and use `UITableViewCell`, and add the additional line of code that casts it to the appropriate subclass.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not like it when you try to cast down the inheritance tree (towards a more specific subclass) because the static analyzer cannot make any guarantee that the interface of the cast target is compatible with the type you say it is.  Block signatures require a little more care than objects because they necessarily care about the types of their arguments, as it determines capture semantics.  You can use `id` to silence the warning because of its type neutrality.  It isn't inconsistent, so much as showing you the result of "opting out" of type safety.  You can very well do the same casting with the `UITableViewCell` signature and come out clean.  Don't turn off the warning, adjust your `typedef` to be more specific, or if necessary, more generic with `id` or cast the necessary parameters.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, adjusting the `typedef` won't work for my use case where I want the block signature generic. I just want a way to opt out of this error for this one assignment.  Hopefully something better than `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored`? Switching to `id` seems like a bad idea because I'll have to cast anyway and I lose the semantics that indicate that the parameter is some type of cell.